# Multiple clusters in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am a newbie in kubernetes clustering. I have a simple question.
I am in multiple kubernetes clustering. It seems multiple clusters are available in kubernetes. So "Multiple clustering" in kubernetes means:

> - It is physical multiple clusters which have their own master, nodes?
> - Or it's kind of "logical" multiple clustering in one physical clustering?(with one master and nodes)?

Would you like to teach me? Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about [federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/)?

Comment: Yes. I think so. Federation.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - Is it a physical isolated cluster? or "logical clusters" in one physical cluster?

Comment: Federation involves multiple physical clusters, each of which has their own master and nodes. Its basically about sync'ing workload configurations and DNS across multiple clusters.

Comment: This guide maybe useful. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems this has been answered by @[Jonah Benton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6716781/jonah-benton) and @[Oliver Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oliver-charlesworth) in the comments. Using [kubernetes cluster federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/) means using multiple kubernetes clusters as though they were one. It is a set of distinct clusters acting as one, not a logical division within a single cluster. (Something like that idea of a logical division might resemble a [namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/), which allows for working with a restricted 'part' of a cluster in terms of resource-allowance but a namespace isn't restricted to particular nodes.) In addition to the links provided, the kubernetes documentation also has resources for [deploying to a cluster federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/federation/) and that page includes links for setting up a federation.

I guess you know this now as the question is a little old but I thought it would help to fill in an answer.

Comment: It may be worth noting the current text of the cluster federation page is: ```Use of Federation v1 is strongly discouraged. Federation V1 never achieved GA status and is no longer under active development. Documentation is for historical purposes only.```