# How to deploy an app into multiple machines on kubernetes simultaneously?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, containers, devops

I'm trying to automate the process of simultaneously deploying an app onto multiple machines with kubernetes clusters. I'm new to kubernetes.

Which tool/technology should I use for this?

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052220/multiple-clusters-in-kubernetes)?

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes doesn't really think in terms of machines (nodes in k8s jargon). When you set up a Deployment object, you specify a number of replicas to create, that's how many copies of the Pod to run. So rather than deploying on multiple machines, you create/update the Deployment once and set it to have multiple replicas which then get run on your cluster.

Answer (score 2):

In kubernetes, you can control the nodes no which service to deploy or if multiple pods of same application should not be deployed on same node. Use `node-selector` or `node-affinity` or `node-anti-affinity`. For details check https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/